# Flutter Web How to export to HTML

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Today I started to test the flutter-web and exported my app:
[Flutter Recipes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=recipes.meir.com.flutter_recipes).
It is amazing and I successfully made this app as a nice web app.

The question is very simple: how do I take this code and export it to HTML in order of uploading it into web?

Answer (score 0):

To build your app for release run the following command in your app directory.

```
webdev build
```

After that you'll see a new build folder with your packages and your index.html and dart.js files. You can use that to deploy.

Comment: No, I tested it before an getting: webdev could not run for this project.
Dart 2.2.0 is incompatible with your dependencies' SDK constraints. Please run "pub get" again.

Comment: Did you run 'pub get' again? and Is your dart updated to 2.3? And are you on the latest Flutter?

Comment: I upgraded to 2.3, but now I get: The Flutter SDK is not available

Comment: @Meir Then this is not a dev problem to solve. You should setup your environment properly then everything will work as expected. Make sure the latest flutter is installed and it's in your PATH. Run flutter upgrade then put the bin folder in your path to your Flutter sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
Package url_launcher did it. When I removed this package, everything is OK.
You can see the page at [Flutter Recipes](http://album.yt/flutter/#/)

Thank you for trying

Comment: I was able to build but when I run my index.html it opens a blank page how did your deploy your site @ http://album.yt/flutter/#/

Answer (score 0):

**Publish your Flutter/Dart web application**

Install Peanut

```
flutter pub global run peanut
```

Run Peanut

```
flutter pub global run peanut
```

For more info:

Use [Peanut](https://pub.dev/packages/peanut) to publish your web page to GitHub pages.

[Here](https://medium.com/@kevmoo/show-off-your-flutter-dart-web-app-with-peanut-c0307f2b733c) you can find how to use Peanut to deploy your Flutter/Dart web application to GitHub Pages.

Here is another [tutorial](https://youtu.be/ajSliNbczi0) by Flutter GDE Pawan Kumar shows how he published his portfolio site made with flutter in GitHub pages. I think you go in the same way.